# Get specific sentence of text files

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following text file :

```
====================================================================================
INDEXNUMARTICLE: '1997'
FILE: '###\www.kkk.com\kompas-pront\0004\25\economic\index.htm' NUMSENT: '22' DOMAIN: 'economic'
====================================================================================

2. Social change is a general term which refers to:  
4. change in social structure: the nature, the social institutions.
6. When behaviour pattern changes in large numbers, and is visible and sustained, it results in a social change.
```

I wanna get only the sentence without the numbering and save it in database :

```
=========================================================================
= id = topic    =                      content                          =
=========================================================================
=  1 = economic = Social change is a general term which refers to:      =
                = change in social structure: the nature,               =
                = the social institutions. When behaviour pattern       =
                = changes in large numbers, and is visible and sustained, 
                = it results in a social change.                        =
```

**CODE**

```
function isNumber($string) {
    return preg_match('/^\\s*[0-9]/', $string) > 0;
}

$txt = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/economic.txt";
$lines  = file($txt);

foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
$checkFirstChar = isNumber($line);
if ($checkFirstChar !== false) { 
    $line_parts   = explode(' ', $line); 
    $line_number  = array_shift($line_parts); 

    foreach ($line_parts as $part) {
        if (empty($part)) continue; 
        $parts = array(); 
        $string = implode(' ', $parts);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_file VALUES ('','economic','$string')");
    }  
}
```

}

I have the problem with array, the data that inserted in column content are words by words in different row. please help me. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is to complicated - try this short one:

```
$txt = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/economic.txt";
$lines  = file($txt);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $checkFirstChar = isNumber($line);
    if ($checkFirstChar !== false) {
        //entire text line without number
        $string = substr($line,strpos($line,"")+1);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_file VALUES ('','economic','$string')");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, with regex.

```
$regex = "/[0-9]\. /";

$txt = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/economic.txt";
$str  = file_get_contents($txt);
$index = -1;

//Find the first ocurrence of a number followed by '.' and a whitespace
if(preg_match($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $index = $matches[0][1];
}   

//Remove all the text before that first occurrence
$str = substr($str, $index);

//Replace all the occurrences of number followed by '. ' with ' '
$text = preg_replace($regex, " ", $str);
```